# How to create new column from existing column value in R dynamically

Tags: r

i have data frame called df,how to create new column from existing list column data frame.

my data frame.

```
Policy             Item

Checked           list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "yy@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "T1, R1", VID = "YUY")))

Sample            list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "tt@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "D3, Y3", VID = "RT")))

Processed         list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "pp@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "Y2, LE", VID = "UIU")))
```

my expected data frame.

```
Policy          Processed    Gmail        Descrption  VID

Checked           Valid      yy@gmail       "T1,R1"  "YUY"

Sample            Valid      tt@gmail       "D3,Y3"  "RT"

Processed         Valid      pp@gmail       "Y2,LE"  "UIU"
```

i'm using below code to get my expected dataframe .

```
na_if_null <- function(x) if (is.null(x)) NA else x

new_cols <- lapply(
  Filter(is.list, df),
  function(list_col) {
    names_ <- setNames(nm = unique(do.call(c, lapply(list_col, names))))
    lapply(names_, function(name) sapply(list_col, function(x) 
      trimws(na_if_null(as.list(x)[[name]]))))
  }
)

res <- do.call(
  data.frame,
  c(
    list(df, check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    do.call(c, new_cols)
  )
)
```

But i'm getting below Data frame.please help me to done my post.

```
Policy       Item                                                                                                          Item.Processed    Item.Gmail     Item.Information

Checked      list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "yy@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "T1, R1", VID = "YUY")))    Processed        yy@gmail      list(Descrption = "T1, R1", VID = "YUY")

Sample       list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "tt@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "D3, Y3", VID = "RT")))     Processed        tt@gmail      list(Descrption = "D3, Y3", VID = "RT")  

Processed    list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "pp@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "Y2, LE", VID = "UIU")))    Processed        pp@gmail      list(Descrption = "Y2, LE", VID = "UIU")
```

dput

```
    structure(list(Policy = c("Checked", "Sample", "Processed"), Item = list(
    structure(list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "yy@gmail", Information = list(
        structure(list(Descrption = "T1, R1", VID = "YUY"), .Names = c("Descrption", 
        "VID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Processed", 
    "Gmail", "Information"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "tt@gmail", Information = list(
        structure(list(Descrption = "D3, Y3", VID = "RT"), .Names = c("Descrption", 
        "VID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Processed", 
    "Gmail", "Information"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "pp@gmail", Information = list(
        structure(list(Descrption = "Y2, LE", VID = "UIU"), .Names = c("Descrption", 
        "VID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Processed", 
    "Gmail", "Information"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Policy", "Item"))
```

Sample data frame

```
Policy             colval                                 Item     

Checked         list(PID="4",Bdetail ="ui,89")      list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "yy@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "T1, R1", VID = "YUY")))

Sample          list(PID="7",Bdetail ="ju,78")      list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "tt@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "D3, Y3", VID = "RT")))

Processed       list(PID ="8",Bdetail ="nj,45")     list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "pp@gmail", Information = list(list(Descrption = "Y2, LE", VID = "UIU")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution in base R:

```
dd <- 
cbind(
  dx$Policy,
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(seq_len(nrow(dx)), function(i)unlist(dx$Item[i]))
  )
)

colnames(dd) <- c("Policy","Processed","Gmail","Descrption","VID")

dd

#       Policy      Processed Gmail      Descrption VID  
# [1,] "Checked"   "Valid"   "yy@gmail" "T1, R1"   "YUY"
# [2,] "Sample"    "Valid"   "tt@gmail" "D3, Y3"   "RT" 
# [3,] "Processed" "Valid"   "pp@gmail" "Y2, LE"   "UIU"
```

Basically I am using `unlist` for each item. and Then joining them using the classic `d.call(rbind,llist)`.

### edit

in case you want tu use the same names as the original sub lists you can do something like :

```
colnames(dd) <- c("Policy",gsub(".*[.]","",colnames(dd)[-1]))
```

### data.table solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dx)
dx[, rbindlist(lapply(.SD,function(x)data.table(t(unlist(x))))),Policy]
```

Comment: ,Thanks for response,But I need dynamically not hardcoding column name Policy,Item. please check my post .

Comment: I don't get your point here. do you want to use the same name as the original ones in the sub lists? You are not creating new columns here you are just reashaping your data.

Comment: ,That's not my point ,my point is  need  to check  if the  column class is  list I need to unlist column  remaining column would be  as  it is.why because in my data frame may be I have more than 59 columns in that 2 or 4 list of column will be there.

Comment: It still not a dynamic creation of column here. It is jsut reshaping. Please produce an example more representative of your case and the excepted output and I will be happy to help.

Comment: ,please check my post I  have edited new data frame called Sample data frame

Comment: i'm getting below issues.Error in `[.data.table`(dx, , lapply(.SD, function(x) data.table(t(unlist(x)))),  : 
  All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.

Comment: @kannank fixed now. Sorry I was far from a PC till right now. You can try again the data.table solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done with `unnest` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unnest() %>%
  unnest()
```

**Result:**

```
     Policy Processed    Gmail Descrption VID
1   Checked     Valid yy@gmail     T1, R1 YUY
2    Sample     Valid tt@gmail     D3, Y3  RT
3 Processed     Valid pp@gmail     Y2, LE UIU
```

**Data:**

```
df =     structure(list(Policy = c("Checked", "Sample", "Processed"), Item = list(
  structure(list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "yy@gmail", Information = list(
    structure(list(Descrption = "T1, R1", VID = "YUY"), .Names = c("Descrption", 
                                                                   "VID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Processed", 
                                                                                                                               "Gmail", "Information"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
  structure(list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "tt@gmail", Information = list(
    structure(list(Descrption = "D3, Y3", VID = "RT"), .Names = c("Descrption", 
                                                                  "VID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Processed", 
                                                                                                                              "Gmail", "Information"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
  structure(list(Processed = "Valid", Gmail = "pp@gmail", Information = list(
    structure(list(Descrption = "Y2, LE", VID = "UIU"), .Names = c("Descrption", 
                                                                   "VID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Processed", 
                                                                                                                               "Gmail", "Information"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               3L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Policy", "Item"))
```

**Note:**

Notice I used two passes of `unnest` because there are two levels of lists in your original dataframe. `unnest` automatically flattens all lists in the dataframe and reuses the names, but it does not do it recursively, so you will have to have as many `unnest` as there are list levels.